# pyspark restructure dataframe and export

Tags: pyspark

I tried another method shown here: [Restructuring pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441214/restructuring-pyspark-dataframe) and it was not working with my dataframe.

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
Attribute    Values   ID    Brand    Model
--------------------------------------------
Colour       Red      1     Sony     xyz
Energy       F        2     Samsung  abc
Year         2020     1     Sony     xyz
Energy       C        1     Sony     xyz
Colour       Blue     2     Samsung  abc
```

I need to restructure/pivot my table to look like this:

```
Brand    Model    Colour    Energy     Year
--------------------------------------------
Sony     xyz      Red        C         2020
Samsung  abc      Blue       F         2021
etc...
```

currently I have tried with this code to try to pivot and group by the ID but it isn't allowing me to show and I don't know how to pivot based on 'Attribute' with 'Values' as the value:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType,BooleanType,DoubleType
import pyspark

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[1]") \
    .appName("PySpark Read JSON") \
    .getOrCreate()



df = spark.read.json("examplell.json")

df.printSchema()
df.show()


count = df.select('ID').distinct().count()

df_pivot = df.groupBy('ID').pivot('Attribute').agg('Values')
df_pivot.printSchema()
df_pivot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping at `ID`, you'd need to group by `brand` and `model`. And, use an aggregation function like `first()` in `.agg()`.

```
data_ls = [
    ('colour', 'red', 1, 'sony', 'xyz'),
    ('energy', 'f', 2, 'samsung', 'abc'),
    ('year', '2020', 1, 'sony', 'xyz'),
    ('energy', 'c', 1, 'sony', 'xyz'),
    ('colour', 'blue', 2, 'samsung', 'abc'),
    ('year', '2021', 2, 'samsung', 'abc')
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['attribute', 'values', 'id', 'brand', 'model'])

# +---------+------+---+-------+-----+
# |attribute|values| id|  brand|model|
# +---------+------+---+-------+-----+
# |   colour|   red|  1|   sony|  xyz|
# |   energy|     f|  2|samsung|  abc|
# |     year|  2020|  1|   sony|  xyz|
# |   energy|     c|  1|   sony|  xyz|
# |   colour|  blue|  2|samsung|  abc|
# |     year|  2021|  2|samsung|  abc|
# +---------+------+---+-------+-----+

data_sdf. \
    groupBy(['brand', 'model']). \
    pivot('attribute'). \
    agg(func.first('values')). \
    show()

# +-------+-----+------+------+----+
# |  brand|model|colour|energy|year|
# +-------+-----+------+------+----+
# |   sony|  xyz|   red|     c|2020|
# |samsung|  abc|  blue|     f|2021|
# +-------+-----+------+------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy()` is probably unnecessary, and from your data sample, `Values` cannot be aggregated. Therefore, I suggest the following:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index=[['Brand', 'Model']], columns='Attribute', values='Values')
```

If you run into duplicate value exception because from 'Brand'+'Model' does not create unique index or rows, add 'ID' as part of index. I presume ID is unique once pivoted.